# awk get the next line without consuming it

Tags: awk

For example, I am using `awk` to search for a specific word, let's say `joker`. When I found this word, I need to check on the next line, if a second word is present, let's say `batman`. But there is a problem if I have a file like this :

```
joker
batman joker
batman
```

In this file, `awk` find `joker` at the first line. Then, I use `getline` and check if there is `batman` on this second line. The problem is, if I do that, `awk` will then directly go to the third line, and will miss the `joker` of the second line.

Is there a way with awk to get the next line of a file, without consuming it ?

Concerning the output, I would like to print the lines where both words have been found. In this example, the output is :

```
1-joker 
2-batman joker
```

My expected output was :

```
1-joker 
2-batman joker

2-batman joker 
3-batman
```

Comment: Answer to your question is no. But if you show us your expected output I'm pretty sure we can show you another way of doing it.

Comment: if the file size < your free ram, you can save the file in memory (awk's array), and do the logic in loop.

Comment: I just want to print both lines with their line numbers. I will edit my post and write my expected output.

Comment: `awk` is probably the wrong tool. It is mainly for tabular input.

Comment: @ceving  - nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0}  END{
        for(i=1;i<=NR;i++){ 
            if(a[i]~/joker/ && i+1<=NR && a[i+1]~/batman/){
                print i"-"a[i]
                print i+1"-"a[i+1]RS
            }
        }
    }' file
```

output:

```
1-joker
2-batman joker

2-batman joker
3-batman
```

It loads whole file in array and do the matching logic in the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are very unclear. To get the output you say you want from the sample input you posted you could just do:

```
$ awk -v OFS='-' 'NR>1{print NR-1, prev ORS NR, $0 ORS} {prev=$0}' file
1-joker
2-batman joker

2-batman joker
3-batman
```

If that's not what you're looking for then edit your question to clarify your requirements and provide sample input/output that better demonstrates your needs.